# Instantiate different specialization with the same parameters

Tags: c++, templates, specialization

Consider the class below. I would like to use sometimes the first specialization and sometimes the second, but **with the same template arguments**.

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

// 1
template < typename U, typename V >
class C
{
public: C() {}
};

// 2
template < typename U, typename VT, typename VA >
class C< U, vector<VT, VA> >
{
public: C() {}
};

// 3
template < typename UT, typename UA, typename VT, typename VA >
class C< vector<UT, UA>, vector<VT, VA> >
{
public: C() {}
};

int main() 
{
  C<int, int> a; // 1st
  C<int, vector<int>> b; // 2nd
  C<vector<int>, vector<int>> c; // 3rd
  C<vector<int>, vector<int>> d; // how do I force the instantiation of 2nd?
}
```

Comment: why? THis is a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Tell us why you think you need this , then we can tell you a different way to get there

Comment: there is no difference between 3rd and 4th line in `main` other than what you want them to do, thats not going to work. You could just use a different name, eg `D<vector<int>,vector<int>> d;`

Comment: Please clarify "sometimes". Do you want to alternate between instantiations, have random instantiations, etc? If you want the declarations to look the same, there must be *some* rule to decide which instantiation to create.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I'm not sure how many details I'm allowed to share. The current class uses, in one case the vector, in the other case the vector elements. Most methods are static. I can't change the solution.

Comment: I think what the specializations do is not the most relevant details (I might be wrong though, currently its all foggy), but why you want `C<vector<int>, vector<int>>` to mean 2 different things, and how it should be decided which specialization is picked

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Yes, I could use a different name, but it would be nice to use the same one. I'm not a template guru, so I do not know what is possible and what is not.

Comment: forget about templates and most you know about C++, you have `T c;` and you have `T d;` and now you want `c` and `d` to be of different types, you want `T` to be different form `T`. Its not going to work, because `T` is the same symbol as `T`. You need to distinguish them somehow

Comment: `C< vector<int>::value_type, std::vector<int>>` is the 2nd specialization btw

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I know it won't work as in the example above. I'm looking for a solution with minimal impact. Something similar to a cast (roughly speaking).

Comment: ok. I understand that, but what can change and what can not change? Why do you want both to be `C<vector<int>, vector<int>>` ?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number "what can change" I do not know what better example to give without saying what I am not allowed to say. Imagine a static method that wraps in one case the elements, in the other the vector - the argument is the same, but the performed operations are applied on different data.

Comment: Seeing as `C<vector<int>, vector<int>>` can't mean different things at different times, you're going to need a different solution to whatever your original problem is.

Comment: I suggested you the two simplest solutions already. What you ask for literally is not possible. I am sorry, but I am afraid if you cannot say more we cannot find a solution. You cannot use the same name for 2 types, but you want that.

Comment: @molbdnilo See the answers for 463035818_is_not_a_number.

Comment: whatever "minimal impact" means it must include not using `C<vector<int>, vector<int>>` in both cases.

Comment: fwiw, what you described so far in comments is only how the implementation of the two specialization differs, but why `main` cannot use `C< vector<int>::value_type, std::vector<int>>` remains unclear

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number "remains unclear" The operations must be performed on `vector<int>` (not the actual type - just an example). Considering the example I gave earlier: the wrapper must wrap `vector<int>` - `wrap<vector<int>>`; in the other case the result would be `vector<wrap<int>>`.

Comment: That's again the implementation. I am talking about the two lines in `main`. Why do they need to be the same?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number "Why do they need to be the same" They don't. I might add a third parameter, for instance: `C<vector<int>, vector<int>, first> d;`. I apologize for confusion. Or could use an hypothetical converter:  `C<wrap_it(vector<int>), vector<int>> d;`.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I just need to force the instantiation of the first specialization.

Comment: The only possible solution to your problem is to change the last line of your main function. If you want someone to help you, you must say what kind of changes are allowed. For instance, would a change to `C<some_wrapper_type<vector<int>>, vector<int>> d` be allowed? It would be very frustrating to answer your question only to get a reply that the answer is not acceptible because of the details "you are not allowed to share".

Comment: @joergbrech I tried to make the question as generic as possible. I may not have succeeded. It would be acceptable to have a helper class holding the type to detect which specialization to use. `C<whole<vector<int>, vector<int>> d;`.

Comment: make it `C< vector<int>::value_type, std::vector<int>> d;`. This is the 2nd specialzation

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number yes that might be even better, depending on the unclear use case

Comment: "make it ..." It won't work because the activity must be performed on `vector<int>`. Sorry for the confusion. I seem to have failed to make myself clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a holder type that is convertible to the held instance

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct whole
{
    operator T() const { return t; }
    T t;
};
```

and then change your last line to

```cpp
 C<whole<vector<int>>, vector<int>> d;
```

https://godbolt.org/z/479x9qo6v

Comment: This would work as expected. However, in `C`, the work must be done on the inner type of `whole<T>`, `T`. How do I get it, considering that on other instantiations `U` might be an `int`, for instance?

So, in case `U` is `whole<T>` the work must be done using `T`, otherwise it must be done using `U` (eg `int`).

Comment: You could use SFINAE/concepts together with `if constexpr` in your second specialization. https://godbolt.org/z/KsErjqnox

Comment: @zdf I think what you actually want is a 4th specialization that knows about both the `vector` and its `value_type`

Answer (score 1):

As already discussed in the comments, if you wish to create different types there must be something different in your definition. It can be either the template arguments, or in a way you can achieve that with different constructor arguments, relying on deduction guides to lead to a specific type (but then without providing the template arguments).

A possible way to achieve what you aim for might be with a factory method that gets your arguments and returns an object of the desired type.

Comment: I understand. @joergbrech solution seems simpler. The only problem I am having now is the one I added as a comment in his solution.

Comment: While my solution may be simpler (I am  not sure), a factory method could be better at conveying intent. It might be a bit obscure to introduce a proxy type to enforce a different specialization, and your code would get harder to decipher for someone else or yourself in a couple of weeks.